# Save a message from exchange 2003 in .msg format using WEBDAV, C#

Tags: c#, .net, webdav

in C# .net 2.0, is there a quick and easy way to retrieve a message (including its possible attachments) from exchange 2003 and save it to disk in .MSG (outlook) format.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a lot of luck using [WebDav.NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html) to interact with exchange from C# code.  You should evaluate it and see if it'll do what you're looking to do :-) Best of luck

Comment: WebDav.net 1.3 most certainly can download and create .msg files.  I also endorse this product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same solution. So far, I found :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Exchange_2003_with_WebDav.aspx

It's a demo application that contains all the code necessary to communicate with Exchange with WebDAV.
I didn't try it though.